# Joining many-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables: applications, permissions and applications_permissions

```
|------------|   |------------------------|   |-----------|
|applications|   |applications_permissions|   |permissions|
|------------|   |------------------------|   |-----------|
| id         | <-| application_id         |   | id        |
| price      |   | permission_id          |-> | name      |
|------------|   |------------------------|   |-----------|
```

For applications there are two categories: free and commercial ones (price = '0' and price != '0')

Now I would like to know for every permission how many percent of total applications reference it; And this for both category

Free:

```
id, percentage
1 , 20.0230
2 ,  0.0000
3 ,  0.0312
...
```

Commercial:

```
id, percentage
1 , 18.0460
2 ,  0.0000
3 ,  0.0402
...
```

I have worked out the following query, but it does not include permission ids with no application :/

```
SELECT (SELECT name FROM permissions WHERE id = applications_permissions.permission_id) AS "name",
        100::float * COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(name) FROM applications WHERE price = \'0\') AS "percent"
  FROM applications, applications_permissions
  WHERE applications.id = applications_permissions.application_id 
    AND applications.price = \'0\'
  GROUP BY applications_permissions.permission_id
  ORDER BY percent DESC')
```

How do I do this?
I've been trying for a few hours now (that query, misc JOINs) but it eludes me :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>Simplified. First draft was sup-optimal.</sup>
To compute all in one query:

```
SELECT p.id
     ,(100 * sum((a.price > 0)::int)) / cc.ct AS commercial
     ,(100 * sum((a.price = 0)::int)) / cf.ct AS free
FROM  (SELECT count(*)::float AS ct FROM applications WHERE price > 0) AS cc
     ,(SELECT count(*)::float AS ct FROM applications WHERE price = 0) AS cf
      ,permissions p
LEFT   JOIN applications_permissions ap ON ap.permission_id = p.id
LEFT   JOIN applications a ON a.id = ap.application_id
GROUP  BY 1, cc.ct, cf.ct
ORDER  BY 2 DESC, 3 DESC, 1;
```

Assuming that your price is actually a numeric column - so `0` instead of `'0'`.

This includes `permissions` that have no attached `applications` at all (`LEFT JOIN`).

If there can be `applications` that aren't attached to any `permissions` the lists will not add up to 100 %.

I do the total count (`ct`) once and cast it to `float` in a subquery. The rest of the calculation can be done with integer arithmetic, only the final `/ ct` converts the number to a floating point number. This is fastest and most precise.

---

#### Same with CTEs

If your are open to yet more new stuff: Try the same with [CTEs (Common Table Expressions - WITH queries)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) - available since PostgreSQL 8.4.
It's cleaner and probably slightly faster, because I do both counts in one CTE and have a cheaper `GROUP BY` - both of which could be done with subqueries just as well:

```
WITH  c AS (
    SELECT sum((a.price > 0)::int) AS cc
          ,sum((a.price = 0)::int) AS cf
    FROM   applications
    ), p AS (
    SELECT id
          ,sum((a.price > 0)::int) AS pc
          ,sum((a.price = 0)::int) AS pf
    FROM   permissions p
    LEFT   JOIN applications_permissions ap ON ap.permission_id = p.id
    LEFT   JOIN applications a ON a.id = ap.application_id
    GROUP  BY 1
    )
SELECT p.id
     ,(100 * pc) / cc::float AS commercial
     ,(100 * pf) / cf::float AS free
FROM   c, p
ORDER  BY 2 DESC, 3 DESC, 1;
```

Comment: ERROR:  column "c.ct" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2:      ,(100 * sum((a.price > 0)::int)) / ct AS commercial

Also it should divide by ctfree and ctcomm, so the values are compareable.

Comment: @Tie-fighter: Sorry, forgot to add it to `GROUP BY`. See amended answer.

Comment: The SELECTs in the FROM clause were new to me :)

Comment: @Tie-fighter: If you like the subqueries, you will love CTEs. :) Added a variant to my answer.

Comment: +1 for the CTE mention.  Once you get used to them, subqueries are almost unreadable.

Comment: Is there an easy way to do additional calculations like excluding values rows that do not reach a certain value threshold or difference threshold? (I tried HAVING, but it did not work out. Do you do this with HAVING?)

Comment: @Tie-fighter: Sounds like a case for a `WHERE` clause. Start a new question if that doesn't help.

Comment: I just had an idea, I will give it a try :)

Comment: Minor item. That is a Derived Table (Inline View in Oracle), not a Subquery. In SQL, a Vector Subquery can be placed anywhere that multiple rows are allowed; a Scalar, anywhere that a single row is allowed.  Both are single column.

Answer (score 3):

Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM permissions LEFT OUTER JOIN
applications_permissions as rel on permissions.id = rel.permission_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
applications on rel.application_id = applications.id
```

Comment: How to I incorporate the price = '0' condition?

Comment: If there's no application then the application can't have a price of zero, right? In this instance it's correct behaviour not to return these permissions. Alternatively, use `WHERE price = 0 OR applications.id is null`.

Comment: > right?
Yes.
> WHERE price = 0 OR applications.id is null
Returns 1 for permissions where it should be 0!?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

For the `free` case:

```
SELECT p.id, (100::float * COUNT(p.id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) from Applications)) Percent
FROM Applications a, Permissions p, Applications_Permissions a_p
WHERE a.id = a_p.application_id AND p.id = a_p.permission_id AND a.price = 0
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY Percent DESC
```

Comment: It works but returns 100 for every permission; That is not correct.

Comment: Now the values seem to be correct.
P.S.: It only returns 178 of 213 permissions though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the result in one query:

```
SELECT p.id
, p.name
, (CASE WHEN total.free=0 THEN NULL ELSE 100::float * sub.free::float / total.free::float END) AS percent_free
, (CASE WHEN total.comm=0 THEN NULL ELSE 100::float * sub.comm::float / total.comm::float END) AS percent_comm
FROM permissions AS p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT permission_id
  , SUM(CASE WHEN a.price<=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS free
  , SUM(CASE WHEN a.price>0  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS comm
  FROM applications_permissions AS pa
  JOIN applications AS a ON (pa.application_id=a.id)
  GROUP BY permission_id
) AS sub ON (p.id=sub.permission_id)
, (
  SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN price<=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS free
  , SUM(CASE WHEN price>0  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS comm
  FROM applications
) AS total
```

Or the result only for free applications (respectively commercial applications by changing the where clause):

```
SELECT p.id
, p.name
, (CASE WHEN total.nbr=0 THEN NULL ELSE 100::float * sub.nbr::float / total.nbr::float END) AS percent
FROM permissions AS p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT permission_id, COUNT(*) AS nbr
  FROM applications_permissions AS pa
  JOIN applications AS a ON (pa.application_id=a.id)
  WHERE (a.price<=0)
  GROUP BY permission_id
) AS sub ON (p.id=sub.permission_id)
, (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS nbr
  FROM applications
  WHERE (price<=0)
) AS total
```

Comment: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "a"
LINE 16:     SUM(CASE WHEN a.price<=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS free